# resulting action for manual typing of url to protected areas

Tags: security, user-experience

If a user manually types the URL to a protected area of the site that they don't have access to what should be the resulting action at the controller?

- log the user out
- give them access denied page
- give them a 404
- send them to home page with no explanation (or other location)

I already control the displaying of the links to get to these areas so I am just concerned with the manual typing to these areas.

I realize this may be subjective and there may not be a correct answer, so I am looking for best practices, explanation, and pros and cons, with focus on security first (if there are concerns) and user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just be careful that you don't generate malformed URLs (or other sites don't redirect to your site with possibly malformed URLs (which isn't unlikely)), or users will be very unhappy with any of the below. I'm sure you can figure out how much with each. I've had this happen to me repeatedly from the same site with newsletter e-mails (they preferred (4)).

All except the first is common practice.

1. Log the user out

   This is probably the number 1 option for security (and number 4 for user experience). If the user is messing around with the URL, they could be trying to do something malicious. You may also want to give them a warning, log the request and ban if it keeps happening for the same user.
2. Give them access denied page

   Slightly less secure than (3) since you're telling the user that something exists there.
3. Give them a 404

   Makes perfect sense.
4. Send them to home page with no explanation (or other location)

   If you have malformed URLs anywhere, this would be a preferred choice for user experience (although it can still not ideal - it can still cause a lot of frustration).

In my opinion, (3) and (4) are practically identical in terms of security.

Answer (score 0):

For me I either display a page that says they do not have access to this page, or else I'll just redirect them to the home page. (the second is my usual choice) However, like you said, the answer is subjective. Pros and Cons, however, exist.

For logging the user out, that would be highly frustrating for the user. Also there's not much point to this when you can simply display a page that says they don't have access or just redirect them.

Obviously don't give them access to something they shouldn't have access to. That defeats the purpose of security.

A 404 Code means the page is not found/does not exist. This is not true, of course, because the page does exist, they just don't have rights to it.

Sending them to the home page is effective and it shouldn't affect the user experience much if at all.

Probably the one that is best for the user is to display a page that tells them they don't have rights to access that page. That way, they know why they're not reaching the destination they wanted.

Once again, it's up to you how you implement it.